# Confirmação de cadastro

Tags: php

Estou tentando fazer enviar um email para validar o cadastro de um usuário, este e meu codigo.

```
    $id = mysql_insert_id($connect);

    // Criar as variaveis para validar o email
    $url =sprintf( 'id=%s&email=%s&uid=%s&key=%s',$id, md5($email), 
    md5($uid),md5($data_ts));


    $mensagem = 'Para confirmar seu cadastro acesse o link:'."\n";
    $mensagem .= sprintf('http://www.gomap.eco.br/ativar.php?%s',$url);

    $headers = "From:".$from;
    mail($to,$subject,$mensagem,$headers);
```

Porem quando coloco essa parte o email não e enviado:
     $id = mysql_insert_id($connect);

O que devo fazer?

Comment: Qual versão do PHP?

Comment: Esta extensão está obsoleta desde o PHP 5.5.0 e foi removida no PHP 7.0.0. Utilize MySQLi ou PDO_MySQL alternativamente. http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo !

Comment: Nao aparece nenhum erro na tela, ou nos logs de erro ha verificou?

Answer (score 0):

A extensão `mysql` está obsoleta, em seu lugar utilize a `mysqli`. Para mais detalhes consulte a [documentação](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php)